# Using class attributes to store meta data

Tags: python-3.x

I am handling a lot of data and sometimes I forget what I did a few months back to get the results that I am reading. And because of the large amount of stuff I have to deal with, it is not feasible to write comment blocks to document everything.

The way I am approaching it now is to create classes for the data I want to process, and then make class attributes that store information such as which data files have been used to compile this result (code logic is still in comments within the codes that generated the results).

In this case, an example would be: I am importing data from a body of text. So for each text I would like to retain information such as date written, author, etc. In my case, I am storing everything using pickle.

I have approximately 100 texts, and I want to do some processing on the collection of texts in a way that uses data from all the different texts. For example, I want to create data for texts that are written in certain years. Or, I could want to check data only from a certain author, or a cluster of texts, etc. Because of that, I end up with processed data that may be generated from different functions, that contain texts from all over.  So instead of manually identifying which texts to include (error bound), I would go to the directory with all the texts, and run a loop that opens the pickle, checks if the 'meta data' satisfies certain conditions, add the data into my results if so. And then get the new results pickle to include it's own 'meta data' for me to reference when I need it again.

My question is, are there any pitfalls that I should be aware of when taking such an approach? And is there a better way to do something like this?

Edit: Added an example.

Comment: Could you provide an example? It's not at all clear why having an attribute in each class is any more or less feasible than putting the same information into its docstrings.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tend to forget that people are not as acquainted to my problem as I am.

Comment: Could you provide an example **of code**? This is a programming site!